# Versatile, multi-site blog feeder

Tags: rss, blogs

I am looking for an open source blog system..

I would like to find something with a single sign on (with existing application), multiple sites, rss feed and all be hosted from the same location.

Don't need too much crazy functionality.. but standard I guess. As far as hacking it up, the less learning curve the better. I have a hard time getting into the nitty gritty of wordpress..

I would like to fetch all the blogs from other sites via an xml/rss/JSON request.. and handle and process the information myself..

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring the internet for friggin ever. I came across PyroCMS which is built on CodeIgniter and it is THE best. Simple enough yet powerful. Versatile. Multisite in the Pro license. All in all very awesome.

www.PyroCMS.com

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress along with WPMU or Buddypress is quite good and easy to learn. Can't imagine anything being any easier to learn with the type of functionality you require.
Best part is that due to all the free plugins available it will be easier for you to modify wordpress according to your requirements.

Give wordpress another try, I'm sure you'll love it once you get the hang of it.

All the best!